# Recreating CSS pseudo-classes in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I am trying to add a little animation with jQuery to my navigation bar. Right now I have the sub menus of the nav bar changing from display:none to display:block with the css :hover pseudo-class. As I said, I am trying to do this with jQuery, so I need to create a selector that was similar to the one I used in my css. The selector I was using that would only display it's child list is:

```
#nav ul li:hover > ul
```

And this worked perfectly, however I obviously can not use the :hover pseudo-class within a jQuery selector, I have tried to use the .hover() method like this (this is without any animations yet):

```
 $('#nav ul li').hover(function() {
 $('#nav ul li').children('ul').css('display','block');
 }, function() {
 $('#nav ul li').children('ul').css('display','none');
 });
```

However, this shows all the sub menus if I hover over *any* of the list items. Here are a couple of jsfiddle examples:

What it looks like with css (and what I want to recreate with jQuery):http://jsfiddle.net/FHdLC/

The result of the jQuery code above: http://jsfiddle.net/LBK3T/

Thanks very much for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `this` to refer to the current **element** inside the [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) handlers, like this:

```
$('#nav ul li').hover(function() {
   $(this).children('ul').css('display','block');
}, function() {
   $(this).children('ul').css('display','none');
});
```

[Here's your example working with the code above](http://jsfiddle.net/LBK3T/1/) :)

Also, you can shorten it down even further using just [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), like this:

```
$('#nav ul li').hover(function() {
   $(this).children('ul').toggle();
});​
```

[You can test the `.toggle()` version here](http://jsfiddle.net/LBK3T/2/)

Comment: Thanks Nick, seems like you always answer all my jQuery questions, and they always are great answers. Thanks so much, I'll mark this as the correct answer as soon as I am able.

Comment: This worked out even better with expected! I used the toggle method, but changed it to "slideToggle()" and achieved my animation effect super easily! Thanks again!

Comment: @Ben - Welcome :) if you get animation queue problems (build-up) from rapidly hovering in/out, add a `.stop(true, true)` just before the `.sligeToggle()` ;)